# RSS feed showing deleted post

Tags: customization, rss, feed

I'm having issues with the RSS feed on the blog I just set up.

When I go to /feed, I see an old post that I've since deleted. But when I go to /?feed=rss (which redirects to /feed/rss), I see the correct feed.

Additionally, after after signing in as admin, /feed returns the expected result.

I'm confused as to where the "incorrect" feed is coming from. Is it being cached somewhere?

FYI I'm on 3.01, and the message "An automated WordPress update has failed to complete - please attempt the update again now." shows up in the dashboard. When I try to re-install 3.01, as the message suggestions, it hangs forever.

Thanks!

Comment: *@Emmett* - What plugins do you have activated? Where is the site hosted and on what plan? Can you point to the actual feed URLs *(assuming you don't mind?)* Also, you might want to post another question to help you resolve your *"update failed to complete"* problem.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't /feed/rss the rss1, while /feed the rss2 (the wp default)?

For the upgrade message, delete the .maintenance file in your site's root dir, and do a manual upgrade if the automated one failed.

Re the deleted post, do a hard refresh. The expiry date of your feed might be erroneous or something like that, and a proxy or your system might be using a cached version of your feed indeed.